# React- ContectApi

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

Getting empty array in useContext in section component initially due to which the section component is empty .Please help me fix this.

//this is my context component

```
export const Products = createContext();

export const ProductContext = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("https://demo7303877.mockable.io");
      const items = await res.json();
      console.log(items);
      // console.log(items.products);
      setState(items);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Products.Provider value={[state, setState]}>
      {props.children}
    </Products.Provider>
  );
};
```

//getting empty array initially in state
//this is section component

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { Products } from "../Context/ProductsContext";

function Section() {
  const [state, setState] = useContext(Products);
console.log (state) //this return an empty array initially

return (
    <div>
      {state.length > 1 &&
        state.products.map((p) => {
          return <p> {p.brand}</p>;
        })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Section;
```

Comment: It returns an empty array initially because rendering is synchronous and fetching is asynchronous. You need to deal with the case data hasn't arrived yet and display UI for it (a loader or shimmer for example) appropriately. Alternatively you can use suspense but that's more to learn (and would require a suspense barrier with a loader anyway).

Comment: I have done exact same in previous task and it works, its not working in this one. Nothing is being displayed even after that data has arrived .